# Kion oni kantas por celebri naskiĝtagon?

Tags: culture

Kion oni kantas dum naskiĝtagfesto?

Ĉu oni uzas "Feliĉan naskiĝtagon"?

Ĉu unu melodio enradikiĝis?

Answer (score 3):

Ni kutime kantis

Ĝojan tagon al vi!
Ĝojan tagon al vi!
Ĝojan tagon kara (nomo)!
Ĝojan tagon al vi!

laŭ la konata melodio de *Happy Birthday* to you.

Answer (score 3):

Vidu [Bondezirojn al vi](https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bondezirojn_al_vi) je Vikipedio.

Comment: Tiu vere estas bona ligilo, sed la respondo povus pliboniĝi - per citata teksto kaj propa klarigo(http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers).

Answer (score 2):

En mia regiono, la kutimo inter multaj e-istoj estas kanti la jenajn vortojn laŭ Kebekia melodio:

Kar[eg]a [nomo]

Jen via vico

Korkantas ni al vi kun am'

[ripetu dufoje]

Jen la melodio:

https://youtu.be/gV7fVZFkpOc

Mi prezentis tion al la partoprenantoj de REF en Sikonda antaŭ jardeko, forgesinte en la momento ke ĉeestas viro kiu estas originale el Kebekio.